# Get text data from a url and refresh it

Tags: php, url, refresh, reload

I have already made it sofar that i get the data but how can i let it refresh every 5 sec so the data will be renewd without reloading the whole page? And how can i make this nicer? I make it now in CSS that it is like:

```
user - game
user - game
user - game
```

But i think it can also already be done in the PHP, right?

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $doc->recover = true;

    $doc->loadHTMLFile('https://example.com');

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $usersquery = "//div[@class='card-header']/h5/a/span[2]";
    $users = $xpath->query($usersquery);
    $uservar = $users->item->textContent;
    
    $gamequery = "//div[@class='collapse']/div";
    $games = $xpath->query($gamequery);
    $gamevar = $games->item->textContent;
    
    echo '<ul class="users">';
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo '<li>'. $uservar[] = $user->textContent . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    
    echo '<ul class="games">';
    foreach ($games as $game) {
        echo '<li>'. $gamevar[] = $game->textContent . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: If I am understanding the question you probably want to look into using JavaScript and Xhr Requests (ajax). Or better yet now days, look at web sockets, and stop long polling.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question a little? Make it more clear what you are specifically asking?